# How to find and remove dependency on bdertc in Delphi XE7 or later?

Tags: delphi, bde

I have a legacy app that years ago used the old Borland Database Engine (BDE), but no longer needs it.  I upgraded to Delphi XE7 last year, and now it will not build my app, as gives the following error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'bdertl' not found

The problem is, I cannot find where my project has this dependency, so I cannot remove it!  Any pointers greatly appreciated! Regards

Comment: Are you trying to build your project with runtime packages?

Comment: Yes, I am - if I don't, I run into other problems with packages I have written.  I don't know whether I really need runtime packages or not, to be honest...

Comment: The few times I've built a project using runtime packages, I've always compiled the project to a plain .Exe first.  Building a plain (stand-alone) .Exe avoids runtime dependency on other packages so is a good thing, by and large.  Better to sort out your probs with building a stand-alone .Exe, imo.

Comment: There might be another package that you are using that is linking to bdertl. Another option is that there could be a reference to it somewhere. I would do a text search for bdertl in your project source folder (and if you can in the packages too).

Comment: Remove stuff until the error goes away. The last thing you removed had the final ref.

Comment: Have you tried installing [Embarcadero's BDE Installer for RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder XE8](http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/30185) ?

Comment: Okay, more info - this problem persists!  I need runtime packages because I am using TMS Plugin Framework, which depends on runtime packages.  I also can't really remove stuff, as that doesn't make sense here.  I did install the BDE on my system, but I really need to get rid of this, as I don't want to have this byte me when Embarcadero stops making that an option.  And Graymatter, I've tried that, and cannot find it there!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling a *program*  or *library* project, then your project options include a setting named *runtime packages*, which is a list of names of packages that Delphi expects your program to use. That list probably includes *bdertl*. Remove that entry, or disable the *link with runtime packages* option. [Previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13777998/33732) have described the settings in more detail, including pictures.

If you are compiling a *package* project, then your project includes a section called the *requires* list (adjacent to the *contains* list). That list includes an entry for *bdertl*; delete it.

Comment: I had tried looking there, and just checked again - I cannot find bdertl.  Could there some indirect dependency going on, and if so, how can I walk that tree?

Comment: Have you checked project `Runtime Packages` settings for all build configurations? You see newer Delphi versions have multiplatform support project options were changed a bit so that now you have one set of settings `All Configurations` which is used for settings common to all platforms and then additional sets for specific platforms and specific configurations (debug and release configuration). these specific configurations inherit settings from `All Configurations` settings set so you need to check that also.

Comment: Also if you are using some third party components that ship with precompiled dcu's it is possible that one of them have been compiled to use runtime packages. So I recommend you also carefully examine available documentation for each third party component you use about their dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I did.  I only have packages listed in "Value from All configurations - 32-bit Windows platform", and there is no bdertl in it; the other two are blanks.

Comment: You might also try just grepping for that phrase in your project directory.